# How to create modeless dialog with electron?

Tags: atom-editor, electron

I want to create a modeless dialog with electron, but I found nothing about this topic in the official documents. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in its [Quick Start guide](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.34.0/tutorial/quick-start/):

> Electron enables you to create desktop applications **with pure JavaScript** by providing a runtime with rich native (operating system) APIs. You could see it as a variant of the Node.js runtime that is focused on desktop applications instead of web servers.
>
> This doesn't mean Electron is a JavaScript binding to graphical user interface (GUI) libraries. **Instead, Electron uses web pages as its GUI**, so you could also see it as a minimal Chromium browser, controlled by JavaScript.

So, just use HTML, CSS and javascript! By instance you can use the [dialog native element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) or any other library like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), [Vex](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/), [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/), etc.